# プログラムの処理時間表示が0.0になる

Tags: python, python3

処理時間を調べたくて、実験的にネットでよく見かけるコードでテストをしてみたのですが、0秒となってうまくいきません。どう手直しすればよいのでしょうか？

```
import time

def main():

    start = time.time()

    i = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        i = i * 2

    end = time.time()

    print (end-start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

[出力結果]：0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

処理がごく短時間で終わってしまうので、計測するには`time.time()`では精度が不十分なのかも知れません。
代わりに`time.perf_counter()`を使ってみてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

time.time()は、システムによっては１秒より高い精度で時刻を提供するとは限らないとなっています。使用しているシステムでは、time.time()の精度が十分でないようです。

Python には、コードの実行時間を計測するモジュールに`timeit`があるのでそれを使ってみたらどうですか。今回のコードであれば以下のようになります。

```
import timeit

def main():
    i = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        i = i * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit('main()', number=1))
```

Jupyter Notebook を使用すると`%timeit`というマジックコマンドが使えて便利です。複数行になる場合は、`%%timeit`を使って以下のようにして計測できるので手軽に使えます。

```
%%timeit
i = 0
for i in range(100000):
    i = i * 2
```

なお、Jupyter Notebook をインストールするのが面倒な場合は、[Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) が無料で使えます。